# Using d3.selectAll with nested json

Tags: json, backbone.js, d3.js, nested

Here i want to create bars for each album with the numbers of 'a_tracks' but i can't get into the node "album".

```
[
    {
        "blazz" : "HisName",
        "firstname" : "HisFirstname",
        "album" :
            [
                {
                    "a_name" : "titlehere",
                    "a_sells" : 90,
                    "a_years" : 2000,
                    "a_tracks" : 12
                }
                ,
                {
                    "a_name" : "othertitlehere",
                    "a_sells" : 200,
                    "a_years" : 2000,
                    "a_tracks" : 8
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

I try this but it's not working :

```
  d3.json('data.json', function(data){
    var albums = data.map(function(d) { return d.album });

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append('svg')
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height",500)

    canvas.selectAll("rect")
      .data(albums)
      .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr('width', function(d){ return d.a_tracks*10;})
        .attr('height',50)
        .attr('y',function(d,i){ return i * 52;})
        .attr('fill','blue')
```

I'm on the wrong way to do this ?
(Json is given a my backbone collection)

Comment: It sounds like you want a nested selection, i.e. `canvas.selectAll("g").data(albums).enter().append("g").selectAll("rect").data(function(d) { return d; }).enter().append("rect")`.

Comment: It on it for 4 hours now...
You save my life, I was just about to kill myself haha !!
Thank you ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on what @LarsKotthoff said in the comments...

The problem you are having here is that the `"album"` property of each item in your original data contains an Array of albums rather than an Object representing a single album. So when you map your data into the variable called `albums`, that variable becomes an array of arrays rather than an array of objects.

Because of this, when you try to set an element's width based on `d.a_tracks` an error will be thrown because `d` is an array, and therefore doesn't have a property called `a_tracks`. In fact it is an array that contains multiple objects which *each* have an `a_tracks` property.

To work around this, you can use a nested selection as was suggested:

```
canvas.selectAll("g")
  .data(albums)
  .enter().append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
      .data(f‌​unction(d) { return d; })
      .enter().append("rect")
```

First, the data `albums` is bound to the incoming `g` (group) elements, which reflects the fact that each item in this data represents a group of albums rather than a single album. Then *within* the group selection, a new selection is created, binding each album in each group to an individual `rect` element.

Comment: Ok, thank you !
So do you think it's better to use this method or to rewrite my json ? I just start the project, so i can still change the json.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using this method, and your data format makes pretty good sense to me. You might want to change `"album"` to `"albums"` just to be clear that it is meant to be an array rather than a single album, but I see nothing wrong with doing it this way.